# DVDs don't play after installing the restricted packages

Tags: dvd, playback

I've installed the Ubuntu restricted area packages tried several things but no DVD play.
AUDIO CD works fine, I built this system especially for linux all new hardware.
dvd drive worked fine in a windows system. could it be a hardware issue, perhaps the drive
having no specific name brand such as sony or lite on?

Answer (score 1):

try installing libdvdcss

Open Terminal and paste this

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

and Enter

then

```
sudo apt-get install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu
```

now

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss
```

you should no be able to play DVDs

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem might also be that the DVD is encrypted.

You need the libdvdread4 package which should be installed in Ubuntu 12.04 but which must be configured to work. Run this command in a Terminal

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

and try to play the DVD again.

You can get some more infos [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) in the official Ubuntu wiki.

Answer (score 0):

A handful of drive manufacturers enforce regioning at the hardware level, which was the problem I had on my MacBook. If the above answers don't work, you can investigate your drive to see if this is the situation.